# How to grab all hive files after a certain date for s3 upload (python)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ls, distcp, s3distcp

I'm writing a program for a daily upload to s3 of all our hive tables from a particular db.
This database contains records from many years ago, however, and is way too large for a full copy/distcp.

I want to search the entire directory in HDFS that contains the db, and **only grab the files with a last_modified_date that's after a specified (input) date**.

I will then do the full distcp of these matching files to s3. (If I need to just copy down the paths/names of the matching files in a separate file, and then distcp from this extra file, that's fine too.)

Looking online, I've found that I can sort the files by their last modified date using the `-t` flag, so I started out with something like this: `hdfs dfs -ls -R -t <path_to_db>`, but this isn't enough. It's printing like 500000 files and I still need to figure out how to trim the ones that are from before this input date...

**EDIT:** I'm writing a Python script, sorry for not clarifying initially!

**EDIT pt2:** I should note that I need to traverse several thousand, or even several hundred thousand files. I've written a basic script in an attempt to solve my problem, but it takes an incredibly long time to run. Need a way to speed up the process....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you use Java but here is an [example of what can do:](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-there-anyway-to-get-last-access-time-of-hdfs-files/td-p/153375). I mad some small modifications to use lastModified.

> ```
> import java.io.*;
> import java.util.*;
> import java.net.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
> import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
>
>
> // For Date Conversion from long to human readable.
> import java.text.DateFormat;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Calendar;
> import java.util.Date;
>
> public class FileStatusChecker {
>     public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
>         try{
>             FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
>             String hdfsFilePath = "hdfs://My-NN-HA/Demos/SparkDemos/inputFile.txt";
>             FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(hdfsFilePath));  // you need to pass in your hdfs path
>
>             for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
>                 long lastModifiedTimeLong = status[i].lastModified();
>                 Date lastModifiedTimeDate = new Date(lastModifiedTimeLong);
>                 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
>                 System.out.println("The file '"+ hdfsFilePath + "' was accessed last at: "+ df.format(lastModifiedTimeDate));
>             }
>         }catch(Exception e){
>             System.out.println("File not found");
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

It would enable you to create a list of files and do "things" with them.

Comment: this is great, but I need to find a python equivalent... sorry for not specifying!

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebHDFS to pull the exact same information:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

This might be more friendly to use with Python.

[Examples](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html):

> Status of a File/Directory Submit a HTTP GET request.
>
> ```
> curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=GETFILESTATUS"
>  The client receives a response with a FileStatus JSON object:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> {
>   "FileStatus":
>   {
>     "accessTime"      : 0,
>     "blockSize"       : 0,
>     "group"           : "supergroup",
>     "length"          : 0,             //in bytes, zero for directories
>     "modificationTime": 1320173277227,
>     "owner"           : "webuser",
>     "pathSuffix"      : "",
>     "permission"      : "777",
>     "replication"     : 0,
>     "type"            : "DIRECTORY"    //enum {FILE, DIRECTORY}
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> List a Directory Submit a HTTP GET request.
>
> ```
> curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"
>  The client receives a response with a FileStatuses JSON object:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 427
>
> {
>   "FileStatuses":
>   {
>     "FileStatus":
>     [
>       {
>         "accessTime"      : 1320171722771,
>         "blockSize"       : 33554432,
>         "group"           : "supergroup",
>         "length"          : 24930,
>         "modificationTime": 1320171722771,
>         "owner"           : "webuser",
>         "pathSuffix"      : "a.patch",
>         "permission"      : "644",
>         "replication"     : 1,
>         "type"            : "FILE"
>       },
>       {
>         "accessTime"      : 0,
>         "blockSize"       : 0,
>         "group"           : "supergroup",
>         "length"          : 0,
>         "modificationTime": 1320895981256,
>         "owner"           : "szetszwo",
>         "pathSuffix"      : "bar",
>         "permission"      : "711",
>         "replication"     : 0,
>         "type"            : "DIRECTORY"
>       },
>       ...
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```